# How to extract all contents within parentheses

Tags: python, regex

How may I extract all the contents within parentheses?

```
string = "int funt (char* dst, char* src, int length); void bar (int a, short b, unsigned long c) ";

import re
pat = re.compile(r'([^(]+)\s*\(([^)]+)\)\s*(?:,\s*|$)')

lst = [t for t in pat.findall(string)]
print lst
```

is not giving the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\))
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gQ3kS4/35

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\))')
test_str = "int funt (char* dst, char* src, int length); void bar (int a, short b, unsigned long c) "

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

[image]

Comment: how do I write that in python?

Comment: @UrsaMajor i have given the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` for find contents within parentheses :

```
>>> string = "int funt (char* dst, char* src, int length); void bar (int a, short b, unsigned long c) "
>>> l= re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)',string)
['char* dst, char* src, int length', 'int a, short b, unsigned long c']
```

then if you want the words you can `split` them :

```
>>> [i.split() for i in l]
[['char*', 'dst,', 'char*', 'src,', 'int', 'length'], ['int', 'a,', 'short', 'b,', 'unsigned', 'long', 'c']]
```

Comment: name 'l' is not defined

Comment: @UrsaMajor oh ... i miss it , you need to assign the result of `re.findall` to l , i edit the answer